# npm throwing an error at the end of the eslint report

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have an issue when running eslint on my typescript project. I have the following package.json, where I wrote a script to run eslint:

```
{
  "name": "ts-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "transpile": "tsc",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "typescript-eslint-parser": "^14.0.0"
  }
}
```

So now, when I run `npm run ling` I get the right output, with all the error that my code has, that need to be linted. But at the end of the list, I see an npm error:

```
✖ 7 problems (7 errors, 0 warnings)
  6 errors, 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ts-tutorial@1.0.0 lint: `eslint src --ext ts`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ts-tutorial@1.0.0 lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dbugger/.npm/_logs/2018-03-26T16_44_57_459Z-debug.log
```

What is causing this error? I have read the log file, but I cannot understand what is the problem from reading it.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'lint' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v8.9.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prelint', 'lint', 'postlint' ]
5 info lifecycle ts-tutorial@1.0.0~prelint: ts-tutorial@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle ts-tutorial@1.0.0~lint: ts-tutorial@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle ts-tutorial@1.0.0~lint: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle ts-tutorial@1.0.0~lint: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/dbugger/projects/exercises/ts-tutorial/node_modules/.bin:/home/dbugger/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/dbugger/.rbenv/shims:/home/dbugger/.rbenv/bin:/home/dbugger/npm-global/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle ts-tutorial@1.0.0~lint: CWD: /home/dbugger/projects/exercises/ts-tutorial
10 silly lifecycle ts-tutorial@1.0.0~lint: Args: [ '-c', 'eslint src --ext ts' ]
11 silly lifecycle ts-tutorial@1.0.0~lint: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle ts-tutorial@1.0.0~lint: Failed to exec lint script
13 verbose stack Error: ts-tutorial@1.0.0 lint: `eslint src --ext ts`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:280:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid ts-tutorial@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/dbugger/projects/exercises/ts-tutorial
16 verbose Linux 4.13.0-37-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "lint"
18 verbose node v8.9.3
19 verbose npm  v5.5.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error ts-tutorial@1.0.0 lint: `eslint src --ext ts`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the ts-tutorial@1.0.0 lint script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is expected. By design, `eslint` exits with status 1 if there are any linting errors. `npm` interprets this as an error, and it's telling you so.

If you want to suppress the bad exit code, you can use one of the workarounds suggested here: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7933.

Comment: I would have never guessed that. Thank you.

Comment: Glad this was helpful, @EnriqueMorenoTent. For future readers, if you could mark this as the correct answer, that would be great.

Comment: So, a possible "solution" is to change the script into:
`"lint": "eslint src --ext ts; exit 0"`