# eslint not working in my react and webpack app - npm run lint:fix issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint

I am trying to run npm run lint:fix in my react/webpack app.
The command runs and I get ✖ 828 problems (828 errors, 0 warnings)
but then it doesnt fix any of the errors and I get an error message. Im not sure what the error message means, do I need some sort of plugin for eslint to work in webpack? I dont know webpack that well.

```
✖ 828 problems (828 errors, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-with-webpack@1.0.0 lint:fix: `eslint --fix .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-with-webpack@1.0.0 lint:fix script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-with-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:4000",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "node serve.js",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^8.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^7.0.2",
    "eslint": "^7.21.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.14",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: would you mind posting the contents of your `package.json`?

Comment: sure ive just posted it above

Comment: this actually seems to be the intended behavior of `eslint`. it will return a status-code 1 if there are any linting errors. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496789/npm-throwing-an-error-at-the-end-of-the-eslint-report). npm sees a non-zero return code and throws the ELIFECYCLE. If you'd like to suppress the npm output, you can use `npm run lint:fix -s`